# Error in formula field when referencing fields of type: Currency - incompatible data type

Tags: custom-field

**I Keep getting *Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Currency).***

I'm trying to get my custom field to add three items, not all need be required, to get to a "Total Booked Revenue for a specific Quarter"

**Can someone help me out here?  I'm just starting out**

```
AND(((Add_l_Idea_Purchase_Amount__c + Add_l_Pitch_Purchase_Amount__c + Add_l_Video_Purchase_Amount__c) <> 0),
(
AND(

OR(
    (Add_l_Pitch_Purchase_Closed__c=TRUE), (MONTH(Add_l_Pitch_Purchase_Close_Date__c)>3), NULL),
(

AND(

 OR(
    (Add_l_Video_Purchase_Closed__c=TRUE), (MONTH( Add_l_Video_Purchase_Close_Date__c )>3), NULL))),

AND(

OR(
    (Add_l_Idea_Purchase_Closed__c=TRUE), (MONTH(  Add_l_Idea_Purchase_Close_Date__c  )>3), NULL)),
(

AND( 

OR(
    ( Add_l_Idea_Purchase_Amount__c  > 0), ( Add_l_Pitch_Purchase_Amount__c > 0), (Add_l_Video_Purchase_Amount__c > 0))))))
```

Comment: Is it a formula field which is of type 'Checkbox' ? If so maybe you should consider wrapping your logic around a IF function so that you can return and either true or false based on your logic.

Comment: The formula field is for "Currency".  I'm trying to show the total $ value of all additional purchases

Comment: My bad - think you have your answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error says, your formula is returning a boolean condition.

AND(cond1,cond2,cond3) will return a true or false condition.

If you want to determine which currency value is returned, then you will need to wrap your condition in one or more if statements.

```
IF(
    AND(cond1,cond2,cond3)
    ,currencyFieldIfTrue,
    IF(
        AND(cond4,cond5,cond6)
        ,currencyFieldIfTrue2
        ,currencyFieldIfFalse
    )
)
```